# What could cause a Java ScheduleService to not run?

Tags: java, multithreading, service

In my Java application I define a ScheduleService like this:

```
ScheduledService<Void> scheduledService = new ScheduledService<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
               tick();
               return null;
            }
        };
    }
 };
scheduledService.setPeriod(new javafx.util.Duration(TICK_PERIOD.toMillis()));
scheduledService.start();
```

When I trigger the application from IntelliJ it works fine and tick() runs every second. When the application is packaged as an `.exe` using the JavaFX Packager, the service is never started.

The state of the server after I run `.start()` in all cases is `SCHEDULED`. Any ideas what else might be going on? Could something be preventing the creation of threads? Or maybe it's not switching between various threads?

The documentation for `ScheduledService` says (emphasis mine):

> Timing for this class is not absolutely reliable. **A very busy event thread** might introduce some timing lag into the beginning of the execution of the background Task, so very small values for the period or delay are likely to be inaccurate. A delay or period in the hundreds of milliseconds or larger should be fairly reliable.

Is it possible there's some issue with the event thread? Is there a way to inspect it?

After calling `start()`, `scheduleService.getExecutor()` returns `null`. Is that expected?

I tried setting my own executor defined this way:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(32, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, blockingQueue);
scheduledService.setExecutor(threadPoolExecutor);
```

and then I print it out before and after calling start. Before it looks like this:

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4d97d155[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

and afterwards:

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4d97d155[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

So, it is claiming there's an active thread, even though it doesn't seem to be active at all.

**Update**: I removed the mention of a screensaver because I manage to reproduce the issue as a simple `.exe` but I still have the problem that the problem doesn't happen when running it from IntelliJ, it only happens when packaged as an `.exe`.

Comment: may i know why you  return null  in call method which return type is  Void?

Comment: @yudongshen: what else could I return?

Comment: you do not need return at all.

Comment: @yudongshen: my compiler disagrees: `Error:(89, 21) java: missing return statement`

Comment: you right. it is  Void, not void. need a return value.

Comment: If you're using Windows, is there a `PATHEXT` environment variable `SCR`?

Comment: @zlakad: yes, I'm using Windows. I don't exactly know what you mean by the question. I know what environment variables are but not what a `PATHEXT` environment variable is.

Comment: @zlakad: there's an environment variable called `PATHEXT` with this content: `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

Comment: Why don't you add `.SCR` to this `PATHEX` and see what happens - these are the "runnable" extensions.

Comment: @zlakad: asking my customers to modify their environment variables to use my product seems a lot to ask. Not having given it there is not preventing this or any other screensaver from running. Is there a reason why you believe this environment variable would have an effect o  the execution of a SchedulesService?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know for sure - but it came to my mind... If other screen savers CAN run, then I am very likely wrong.

Comment: My screensaver is running as well. Just not spawning background threads or something like that.

Comment: Oh, well.. I'm sorry, I cannot help you. Good luck, friend.

Comment: You seem to be fixated on the `ScheduledService`. What if that's not the issue? Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135982/turn-java-app-into-windows-screensaver)

Comment: @Adelin: I'm not fixating on it, it's the bit that doesn't work. I checked that question and it doesn't add anything to the problem I'm experiencing. Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: I mean - is your program accepting those command line args? It seems that's the criteria for the java app to be executed as a screensaver

Comment: @Adelin: yes, it accepts those arguments and does everything else a screensaver needs. It is a working screensaver already, but the `ScheduledService` is not being triggered.

Comment: Can you take a thread dump and see if something is blocking at the top of the stack?

Comment: How do I take this thread dump?

Comment: Would JVisualVM or JConsole not work?

Comment: @PaulMacGuiheen: No, because the error only happens when my code is being executed as a screensaver, so, I cannot interact with the computer in any way while the error is happening. I'm trying to reproduce it without being in screensaver mode, but so far I haven't succeeded (and I suspect if I succeed I will have found the problem and possibly the solution).

Comment: Maybe you can add some code to help out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958938/how-do-i-create-a-thread-dump-via-jmx

Comment: I may have found the solution. I'll post more soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and it had nothing to do with `ScheduleService`. There were literally three other bugs in my app that were compounding to produce the unexpected behavior as well as hide my attempts at exploring the problem.

Comment: Symptoms do have a sneaky way of looking like problems :)

Comment: : in debug mode it reads a different config file and that's why it was working. Now, there were two other bugs that hidden away the differences in config file, so, I didn't realize that was going on.

Comment: So if I write an arbitrary answer, can I get those points? ;)